# VueJs set active class to the data coming from API, when one li element is clicked in V-for loop

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to set active class to one of the many options, which is coming from API. Also the first option is active at first, and when user clicks it has to toggle.
Below is my template :

```
<div @click="showTimezone">
        <span>{{defaultCountry}}</span>
    </div>
<div  id="timezone-menu" class="timezone-menu" v-show="showTimezone">
          <ul >
            <li class="country-menu-item" v-for="item in Options" :id="item.id" :key="item.abbrevation" @click="selectCountry(item)">
                {{ item.optionText }}
            </li>
          </ul>    
        </div>
```

I stored the data from API in Options array.

```
data() {
     return {
        defaultCountry: "CST",
        Options: [],
    }
   }
```

On the drop down, the CST will be by default Bold. On clicking other option, it should lose its style class and added to the other option which user clicked. Please help me out on how to do this. Will provide additional details if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property called `activeId` to your data object and update it in the `selectCountry` method:

```
data() {
     return {
       defaultCountry: "CST",
       Options: [],
       activeId:-1
    }
    },
methods:{
  selectCountry(item){
    ...
    this.activeId=item.id;
  
  }
}
```

in the template add the class binding :

```
<li class="country-menu-item" :class="{'active':item.id===activeId}" v-for="item in Options"
```

Comment: I'm getting error in compiling the template.                                                                      invalid expression: Unexpected token '.' in
{item.id===activeId?'active':' '}

Comment: try out `<li class="country-menu-item" v-for="item in Options"  :class="{item.id===activeId?'active':''}"`

Comment: what about `:class="item.id===activeId?'active':''"`?

Comment: Thank you, its working now.  Also on default, this option in dropdown should be active. since data is from API, how can we set active by default?                                                        
 '<div @click="showTimezone">
        <span>{{defaultCountry}}</span>
    </div>'

Comment: you could set `activeId` to some country id instead of `-1`